# Derivative under integral mixed with...

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y)=\int_{e^{4y}}^{\ln^3(x)}{\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,dt}$$

*Whats the derivative $\frac{d f}{d t}$, if:*

$$x(t)=\cos(2+6t).4t^2$$
$$y(t)=\ln(2r+7e^{5t})$$

Really not much to say about this problem since I never saw it before.

Ps: Edition has been made but the original question used $\partial f/\partial t$ (partial derivative instead of $d$). Also, if is worth adding, the first part of the question asked to calculate $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$, but did not caused me trouble. I would really appreciate if someone could solve this.

Comment: The title really made me smile :)

Comment: Hint:

Fundamental Theorem of Calculus II and Chain Rule.

Comment: You'll need the [leibnitz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) for that.

Comment: The maker of the problem really shouldn't have used $t$ as the independent variable underlying all the functions *and* the dummy variable inside the integral.

Comment: why is this so complicated. have no idea what purpose knowing how to do this serves. all it uses is $d \int_a^b f(t) dt = f(b) db - f(a) da.$

Comment: Should I calculate the integral and then calculate the derivative? Most of the problems of differentiation under the integral sign asked for derivative with respect to $x$, about $t$, I really don't have an answer.

Comment: I don't know. This teacher tries hard to be hard, but is not willing to take the time it takes to really teach. $s+lc=mq$ Sadism + Low Competence = Messy Questions. Sorry, just typing from the heart.

Comment: @abel Don't see the purpose too, I'm studying cause I don't want to get caught.

Comment: @GregordeCillia All I see is derivatives in respect to $x$ but it asks in respect to $t$...

Comment: You can't calculate the integral --- you can't express $\int(1/t)\sin t\,dt$ in terms of the functions you know. But you can make believe you can calculate the integral by declaring the function $Q(t)$ to have the property $\int(1/t)\sin t\,dt=Q(t)+C$, which tells you $Q'(t)=(1/t)\sin t$, which will come in handy when you come to calculate the derivative.

Comment: So the answer is $\sin t/t$?

Comment: there is no need to know what the indefinite integral $\int \dfrac{\sin t}{t} \ dt$

Comment: @GregMartin the use of $t$ for two different purposes threw me off too.

Comment: @RandyE I'm thinking that maybe she used it to confuse, but I not qualified in math enough to tell if you need to use it or not...

Comment: Maybe. I've made mistakes like this before once or twice, though, and it's been due to sloppiness, not malice towards my students.

Comment: Need to absent from comments because is quite late in Brazil. But, thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Liebniz integral rule to get the result. That is,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}F(w,t)dw = \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(w,t)dw + F(b(t),t)\frac{d b}{dt}(t)-F(a(t),t)\frac{d a}{dt}
$$

In this case you have 
$$
b(t)=\log^3(x(t))=4t^2 \cos(2+6t)
$$
$$
a(t) = \exp(4y(t))=\exp(4\log(2r+7\exp(5(t))))
$$
and
$$
F(w,t) = \frac{\sin(w)}{w}
$$

Notice the last is independent of a time variable $t$, any variable in the integrand is participating in the integration and is in fact a different $t$ than what you are differentiating.